Activity selection problem with reserve activities
How can we solve Activity Selection Problem with reserve activities?
Let's say we have chosen some set u of non-overlapping activities. Now, for every u_i activity, we need to choose reserve activity that is not present in set u, and is overlapping with at most one activity from u, which is u_i.
Any reserve activity can overlap with other reserve activities, as long as it overlaps with at most u_i activity. Reserve activities can be shared among multiple activities from set u.
My approach to solve this problem is following:

Solve basic activty selection problem, so we have set u of length k.
We can observe that if we choose k-th activity from set u, remove it from set u and use it as reserve activity for all activities in set u, then answer to our problem will be k - 1.
Because k is the length of longest possible set of non-overlapping activities, we can improve our answer from k - 1 to k. I'm not sure, but I think it's possible only when for every activity from set u we can assign different reserve activity.

That's my code:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

bool comp(pair<pair<int, int>, int> const &l, pair<pair<int, int>, int> const &r)
{
    return l.first.second < r.first.second;
}

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(nullptr);
    cout.tie(nullptr);

    int n;
    cin >> n;

    vector<pair<pair<int, int>, int>> activities(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> activities[i].first.first >> activities[i].first.second;
        activities[i].second = i;
    }

    sort(activities.begin(), activities.end(), comp);

    int k = 0;
    vector<pair<pair<int, int>, int>> primary_activities;
    primary_activities.reserve(n);
    vector<bool> used(n);
    int end = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (activities[i].first.first >= end)
        {
            ++k;
            primary_activities.push_back(activities[i]);
            end = activities[i].first.second;
            used[activities[i].second] = true;
        }
    }

    vector<int> reserve_activities;
    reserve_activities.reserve(k);

    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
    {
        int l = i - 1 >= 0 ? primary_activities[i - 1].first.second : INT_MIN;
        int r = i + 1 < k ? primary_activities[i + 1].first.first : INT_MAX;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            if (!used[activities[j].second] && activities[j].first.first >= l && activities[j].first.second <= r)
            {
                reserve_activities.push_back(activities[j].second);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (reserve_activities.size() == k)
    {
        cout << k << '\n';
        for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
        {
            cout << (primary_activities[i].second + 1) << ' ' << (reserve_activities[i] + 1) << '\n';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << k - 1 << '\n';
        for (int i = 0; i < k - 1; ++i)
        {
            cout << (primary_activities[i].second + 1) << ' ' << (primary_activities.back().second + 1) << '\n';
        }
    }
}

Firstly, I read input: n (number of given activities), then n lines constisting of activities duration described by range [l, r].
My u set is represented by primary_activities. Here are activities chosen while solving base activity selection problem. Then, for every primary_activities[i], I search for reserve activity such that it starts after previous primary activity (primary_activities[i-1]) ends and such that it ends before next priary activity (primary_activities[i+1]) starts.
In output, I print the k = max length of found set, and then k lines consisting of pairs {primary activity, reserve activity assigned to it} .
I can't find out what's wrong with my logic. This code doesn't pass many testcases, because it often gives too small answer (k-1 instead of k), and of course is too slow.
I believe there must be something like O(NlogN) solution. So how to solve this problem?
Problem statement is from XXXI Polish Olympiad in Informatics, link to original problem statement in Polish

You never need more than one reserve activity for a given set u. A reserve activity would either not overlap any member of u, or overlap exactly one; either way, it's valid for them all. So naively: find the largest set u of length k using the "normal" algorithm. Then among the remaining activities, look for one that overlaps exactly one element of u. If you find one, the answer is k, otherwise it's k-1 (you need to sacrifice one element from the best set to be the reserve activity).

Though my guess is, there are corner cases where more than one k-length "normal" solution is possible, for some of which the additional "overlaps exactly one" activity exists while for others it doesn't. Otherwise the problem wouldn't have been very interesting.

Is the description in the question the original problem statement or your interpretation of what to do?

@Unmitigated I converted story to algorithmic problem, I hope I understood it well. But even if not, I still have no idea how to solve it.

Unfortunately, it's not very clear to me. I'll take a look at the official problem text later.

@IgorTandetnik why if I find reserve activity that overlaps with one activity then answer is k? If some reserve activity overlaps with some primary activity, then it cannot be used as reserve for others because for every u_i, the reserve activity reserve[i] can overlap only with u_i

Ah, right. I misread. Never mind me. There needs to be either one that doesn't overlap with anything at all, or one for each "primary" activity.

The most simple example I can provide is something like this:
4
0 2
1 3
2 4
3 5

Visually it looks like this
Your algorithm choose first and third, so there is no substitution for first lecture (the second lecture overlaps with the chosen third one): visualisation of your solution
But the optimal way to choose core lectures is like this
I think the optimal solution is to simply find substitutions simultaneously with finding the main set of lectures
The fixed code should look like this:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

bool comp(pair<pair<int, int>, int> const &l, pair<pair<int, int>, int> const &r)
{
    return l.first.second < r.first.second;
}

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(nullptr);
    cout.tie(nullptr);

    int n;
    cin >> n;

    vector<pair<pair<int, int>, int>> activities(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> activities[i].first.first >> activities[i].first.second;
        activities[i].second = i;
    }

    sort(activities.begin(), activities.end(), comp);

    vector<int> primary_activities;
    vector<int> reserve_activities;
    primary_activities.reserve(n);
    reserve_activities.reserve(n);

    int primary_end = INT_MIN;
    int reserve_end = INT_MIN;
    int primary_index = 0;
    int reserve_index = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        int previous_primary_end = primary_end;
        while (primary_index < n &&
            (activities[primary_index].first.first < previous_primary_end || 
            activities[primary_index].first.first < reserve_end))
        {
            primary_index++;
        }

        if (primary_index == n)
        {
            break;
        }
        primary_end = activities[primary_index].first.second;

        while (reserve_index < n &&
            (reserve_index == primary_index ||
            activities[reserve_index].first.first < previous_primary_end))
        {
            reserve_index++;
        }

        if (reserve_index == n)
        {
            break;
        }
        reserve_end = activities[reserve_index].first.second;

        primary_activities.push_back(activities[primary_index++].second);
        reserve_activities.push_back(activities[reserve_index++].second);
    }

    cout << primary_activities.size() << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < primary_activities.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << (primary_activities[i] + 1) << ' ' << (reserve_activities[i] + 1) << '\n';
    }
}

I've just applied the idea of "two pointers" to the original algorithm. Let me know if it passes all tests or not.
The solution I provided is O(n)

It doesn't work. It produces result in such a way that reserve_activity[i] overlaps with primary activities other than primary_activity[i]. Try it for the input from problem statement.  (input on left, possible valid output on right)

I think you got the idea (it should work). But anyway I’ll check the implementation, thank’s

I didn't notice the issue in the code. Did you?

I've debugged & fixed the issue. The solution now is updated. Thank's for your note! @Szyszka947 The issue was in the calculations of primary_end & reserved_end. It just was incorrect if nested while cycles ends on the first condition check. Now it seems correct for me and produces the answer without overlaps. If there's any other issues - let me know!

Still doesnt work. Neither k nor k-1 is often on output.  Unfortunately, I don't know specific test cases.
